# Send button shouldn't scroll page to top (HTML, CSS)

Tags: html, css, button, anchor

How can I use my button only for reset data in form but not scroll on top (how can I use anchor inside button)?

```html
<a href="#contacts"><button>Send</button></a>
```

Comment: you have an anchor pointing at `#contacts` element. Just remove that and it won't scroll. The sentence in your question is negating itself... because it's still not clear why you want an anchor if you don't want to scroll. The logics about resetting the form doesn't seem relevant

Comment: FYI: Nesting `button` into `a` is not allowed in HTML to begin with. They are both considered _interactive_ elements, and as such must not be nested.

Answer (score -1):

A button submits anyway.
If this is your only button, you can prevent this with jQuery.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //prevents the scroll to top
  });
});
</script>
```

But what is the reason are you using this button tag? if it is for the styles, you can alternatively write a new line of css, put that in a class and give your anchor tag the class="button" (or whatever name you want).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).